# How to debug a swing UI in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, swing

I am trying to figure out where in some Swing code a UI window is created.  It is ~1 million lines of code (no joke), and I have done a reasonable amount of searching and debugging.

I am looking for a tool where I can click on a window in the UI and it will show me something about its Java code (name of an object, etc).

I am using Eclipse 3.5, and it would be convenient if the tool worked in Eclipse, as I already have the project set up.

Two packages I've seen advertised to do this:

- [UI Debugger In JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)(The download is nearly 1G.  Are they serious?!  1G?)
- [Swing Explorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swing explorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com) met my needs.

Maybe I should close this question.

Comment: No, just "accept" your own answer. Someone else may find this useful.

Comment: That link is now broken